# Combining arrays but second array will add up values for array one

Tags: php, arrays, array-combine

```
<?php
$keys = array(1,1,2,1,1);
$values = array(1,1,1,1,1);
$result = array_combine ($keys, $values);
?>
```

I want to add the second array values. 
For example `$result` will display the output as

```
$result[1] = 4, // it will add the all values for the $keys of 1 ,
$result[2] = 1,
```

Comment: Clear your question a bit more and tell me what is your complete output when you print result correctly also explain logic ?

Comment: `array_count_values` then. And what's the point for second array then?

Comment: It would be more useful if you would add one or two non-trivial examples.

Comment: See, I have arrays that will be names product id, second array is product quantity,, 
So product id = {1,5,65,56,1}
and QQuantity is {5,6,5,6,5}
So answer for product 1 will be 10

Answer (score 1):

You could use a plain `foreach` loop. For given arrays `$keys` and `$values` this will produce `$result`:

```
$result = [];
foreach($keys as $i => $key) {
    $result[$key] = (isset($result[$key]) ? $result[$key] : 0) + $values[$i];
}
```

Comment: No see this example 

array of products is      5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,3  |  

array of quantities is    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,6       |    
   

This means product 5 has 4 quantities ,

product 4 has 5 quantities 

and product 3 has 6

Comment: What is the expected output for that? I mean, the code I provide will output what you describe: https://3v4l.org/2p0au. There must be some misunderstanding...

Comment: @BilalRehman check my code above i have tested and works fine for me

Comment: BTW, this code produces the same results as the answer that was posted later, and where you comment "Exactly this", so now I am really confused...

Comment: @NewtonSingh, if you have something to say about your own code, please post it there, not here.

Comment: I see both comments at a time, so I tried second, This works too.

Comment: Then why did you say "No" in your first comment?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you're expecting to achieve, this is a possible solution:

```
$keys = array(1,1,2,1,1);
$values = array(1,1,1,1,1);

$total = [];

foreach($keys as $index => $key){
    if(!array_key_exists($key, $total)){
        $total[$key] = 0;
    }

    $total[$key] += $values[$index];
}

print_r($total);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$keys = array(1,1,2,1,1);
$values = array(1,1,1,1,1);

$ids = $result = [];
foreach($keys as $index => $key) {
   if (in_array($key, $ids)) {
       $result[$key] += $values[$index]; 
    } else {
       $result[$key] = $values[$index]; 
    }

   $ids[] = $key;
 }

  echo"<pre>";
  print_r($result);
```